# Synology NAS - automatic mount in finder and permanent connection

Tags: itunes, network, finder, smb, nas

I've recently buy Synology DS215j and for almost everything it works fine. But I have two problems with this and Mac OS X.

First I must always first mount this NAS server in finder before using. Sometimes I see it in Shared group in Finder but everytime I tried to click on it and see content it doesn't work and I must first use `Go -> Connect to a server ... -> and fill smb://192...` (or use saved address; maybe I have little different names, because I am translating it from my language). Now for sometime it works ok but when I am not using it and try it after hour I must reconnect.

Second problem could be relative to first one. I moved my music folder to NAS and I used application for creating iTunes Server on NAS and when I created I connect it from my MacBook iTunes and it works. But after a while of listening music it stops and it disconnects and I can't find any iTunes Server available.

Is it normal? I just want to always have my music to available and same with files in Finder that are located on NAS. I guess I have set right settings on both side but I am not sure. Thanks for help

Comment: you will find an answer to a similar question [here](http://superuser.com/a/303011/443279)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding lost iTunes Media Library:

Start iTunes with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> Key down and select NAS Library as new iTunes Library.

Make sure you still have the files `iTunes Libary.itl` and `iTunes Libary.xml` after eventualy deleting 'old' Media Folder.